# Passing a wildcard character within a variable to use with grep in Perl?

Tags: perl, grep, wildcard

I'm attempting to assign a variable a file path with a wildcard character in it and then using that variable in a grep command.  Unfortunately when I run it, the wildcard character isn't seen.  I attempted to use .* instead and even as a regex but neither worked. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm looking to grep all files that starts with ftp_log, so on the command line it would be:

```
grep ftpd ftp_log.* | sed 's/\*//g' > <searchfile>`
```

Can't seem to translate it to work in perl though.

```
$filename = "\/sysadm\/shared\/NCC\/logs\/" . $SYSTEM . "\/ftp_log.*";

`grep ftpd $filename | sed 's/\*//g' > $searchfile`;
```

grep: /sysadm/shared/NCC/logs/sslmlvfp1/ftp_log.: No such file or directory

Thanks.

Comment: Why in the world would you ever want to shell out to `grep` or `sed` from a Perl program?

Comment: Because it gets the job done.  I'm still learning the language...

Comment: If you interactively run `grep` with the full path output by Perl (`grep ftpd /sysadm/shared/NCC/logs/sslmvfp1/ftp_log.*`), does that work?  It looks like you just have the pathname wrong.  (Also, your output message doesn't match your code - it's missing the `*`.  Check your copy/paste.)

Comment: I think that's the problem I'm having is that for some reason the wildcard * isn't being sent, that's exactly how I see it on the screen, I'm not missing anything with the copy/paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have a pathname mismatch; your code looks like it should work - though you don't need to put backslashes in front of `/`s in a Perl string, and you can use interpolation instead of concatenation:

```
my $filename = "/sysadm/shared/NCC/logs/$SYSTEM/ftp_log.*";
```

That said, it's a bit silly to shell out to either `grep` or `sed` from `perl`.  Here's one way to do the equivalent within the Perl program itself:

```
open my $out, '>', $searchfile;
foreach my $filename (glob "/sysadm/shared/NCC/logs/$SYSTEM/ftp_log.*") {
  open my $log, '<', $filename;
  while (<$log>) {
    if (/ftpd/) {
      s/\*//g;
      print $out $_;
    }
  }
  close $log;    
}
close $out;
```

Comment: That looks to have worked.  Thank you.  I will take what you said to heart about shelling it out and will try the code you provided as well.  Thanks again!